# Overload resolution between two constructors from std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list, overload-resolution

In following program, struct `C` has two constructors : one from `std::initializer_list<A>` and the other from `std::initializer_list<B>`. Then an object of the struct is created with `C{{1}}`:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct A {
    int i;
};

struct B {
    constexpr explicit B(int) {}
};

struct C {
    int v;
    constexpr C(std::initializer_list<A>) : v(1) {}
    constexpr C(std::initializer_list<B>) : v(2) {}
};

static_assert( C{{1}}.v == 1 );
```

Since only aggregate `A` can be implicitly constructed from `int`, one could expect that `C(std::initializer_list<A>)` is preferred and the program succeeds. And indeed it does in Clang.

However GCC complains:

```
error: call of overloaded 'C(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
note: candidate: 'constexpr C::C(std::initializer_list<B>)'
note: candidate: 'constexpr C::C(std::initializer_list<A>)'
```

and so does MSVC:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'C'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/joz91q4ed

Which compiler is correct here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wording could be clearer (which is unsurprising), but **GCC and MSVC** are correct here: the relevant rule ([over.ics.list]/7) checks only that

> overload resolution […] chooses a single best constructor […] to perform the initialization of an object of type `X` from the argument initializer list

so the fact that the initialization of `B` from `{1}` would be ill-formed is irrelevant.

There are several such places where implicit conversion sequences are more **liberal** than actual initialization, causing certain cases to be ambiguous even though some of the possibilities wouldn’t actually work.  If the programmer was confused and thought one of those near misses was actually a **better** match, it’s a feature that the ambiguity is reported.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood this *the fact that the initialization of B from {1} would be ill-formed is irrelevant* correctly, then even removing the constructor `B::B(int)` will keep ambiguity, but now all compilers select `A`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3n63nTfrW

Comment: @Fedor Without `B::B(int)` the condition that «overload resolution … chooses a single best constructor» is not satisfied, [over.ics.list]/7 does not apply.

Comment: Thanks, and one more question. If one adds constructor from `int` to `A`, then MSVC starts accepting the code as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zz4b4a6j3. Is it wrong now?

Comment: @Fedor: It seems that way, although I can’t easily explain why MSVC would think that initializing an `A` became a *better* conversion with a constructor.